# Module to make View Tokens available

Tags: views, tokens

I'm looking for a module which adds Views into tokens. E.g within some content, I want to be able to use [view-vid], or something similar.

Is there anyway for me to do this without needing to write custom code?

Answer (score 0):

In D7 you can use a phpsnippet calling [views_embed_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7). Modules to do the job like [Views embed filter](http://drupal.org/project/views_emb_filter) seem to have died at the D6 stage.